# How to save , read and write files in android in external storage?

Tags: java, android, file, sd-card

I'm trying to understand how to work with files in Android

I have installed my android application in external storage

it contain a folder  `data`of files that it need while running...

firstly I think that my folder will saved automatically in the sdcard while installing

but after reading some question here , It seem I should create a folder in which I save my

folder `data`...

I write this question to ask about steps to do to achieve my goal an I need your advances

**Goal**

- Save a folder `data` in external storage , read from it and write a new file

**Steps**

- add permission to manifest file
- create a folder in sdcard ==> how to place my folder there ?
- create a new file , save it on sdcard and write into it

**code**

This is a part of my activity :

```
    {
      ....
       File file = new File ("...")

       doPrediction(file);


}

private void doPrediction (String FileName)

        {

     for (File child : VisualModels.listFiles()) {


     svmPredict.run(MyDataSource.inputPrediction,

         new File( MyDataSource.outputPrediction+ "/"+child.getName()+".predict"), 

         child);
          }
        }
```

I declared the class `svmPredict` as any ordinary java class ans this is the code of `run method`

```
       try 
    {
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
        DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile)));
        svm_model model = new svm().svm_load_model(modelFile);
        if(predict_probability == 1)
        {
            if(svm.svm_check_probability_model(model)==0)
            {
                System.err.print("Model does not support probabiliy estimates\n");
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(svm.svm_check_probability_model(model)!=0)
            {
                svm_predict.info("Model supports probability estimates, but disabled in prediction.\n");
            }
        }
        predict(input,output,model,predict_probability);
        input.close();
        output.close();
    }
```

Comment: @blackbelt I tried to work with files as the traditional java way :put the foldes in the project folder and then read /write 

but It doesn't work situation in android in different

Comment: @blackbelt I can't find any exemple on google of  how to using files in android , 

any tutorials are welcome

Comment: @blackbelt code is posted

Comment: what`s the value of MyDataSource.outputPrediction ? Do you have the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission?

Comment: it is a File I have declared as a static final field in a final class `MyDataSource`

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [Android documentation regarding External Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal).

Pay attention to the [getExternalFilesDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29). You can retrieve the path to the external storage using this method. 
When you have the path, you can use the [File](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html) object to create the data folder on the external storage like this:

```
File dataDirectory = new File(getExternalFilesDir() + "/data/");
```

Then create the folder by applying the mkdirs()-method on the File object:

```
dataDirectory.mkdirs();
```

To write to external storage, you will indeed have to declare this in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```